# Autohotkey Hotstring English Contractions

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following shortcut in auto hotkey.

```
#Hotstring c o
#Hotstring EndChars `n `t
::t::0
```

The following typed out text incorrectly activates the hotstring `don't`.

Comment: If you don't want Space as an ending character, then define **#Hotstring EndChars** without space between Enter and Tab.